# Inheritance and Friends Function in C++

Tags: c++

I read that since a friend function is not a member function, so it is never inherited. I tried following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Base {
    char *m_str;
public:
    Base(void): m_str("Base Default") { }
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & , const Base &);
};

ostream & operator<<(ostream &os , const Base &b) {
    os << "Base String : " << b.m_str << endl;
    return os;
}

class Derived : public Base {
    char *m_dstr;
public:
    Derived(void): Base(), m_dstr("Derived Default") {  }
};
int main(void) {
    Derived obj3;
    cout << obj3;
    return 0;
}
```

And the o/p is :-
Base String : Base Default

My understanding was I should've got error at compile time. But I think it worked because compiler internally used derived object as Base Class reference. Is this reason correct?

Please note that I have directly assigned the string literals addresses to the pointer rather than copying the string into dynamically allocated memory.. This was just for experiment purpose :p

Comment: Try it with non-friend non-member functions.

Comment: "a friend function is not a member function, so it is never inherited". This is rather misleading. A friend finction is just a function and can be called just like any other function. Friendship only matters *inside* the function body.

Comment: " string literals addresses to the pointer rather than copying the string into dynamically allocated memory": You don't need to copy literal string, but you should have uses `const char*` instead of `char*`.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing strange going on here.

Indeed, `operator<<` is a free function that is not part of `Base`, `Base` only specifies that that function is a friend of said class.

Then you proceed to call this function and supply it with a `Derived` object. A `Derived` object *is* a `Base` object too and thus the specified overload for `operator<<` is valid. This has nothing to do with inheriting the function or not and has nothing to do with `friend`.

Try this with any other free function taking a `Base` and it'd be equally valid.

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator<<` is a free function. As such it is neither inherited nor otherwise treated different than every other free function (regardless of the friendship).

Now, when the compiler processes the statement `cout << obj3` the usual overload resolution takes place. In order to do so, the types of the arguments are inspected, which in this case are `std::ostream` and `Derived`. Next, all available functions are considered and the compiler checks whether they can accept arguments of these types. Since `Derived` inherits `Base` and an up-cast is implicit (may be performed by the compiler without you explicitly stating that), every function that takes a `Base` (or `const`/non-`const` pointer/reference to `Base`) may also take a `Derived` and is thus a valid match. This exactly is the case here for your `operator<<`.

Next, all matching overloads are ordered from best match to worst (but still valid) match. The quality of a match is hereby specified by the programming language. If there is a single best match, that one is chosen. In cases where two or more overloads are equally good, overload resolution is ambiguous and the compiler cannot decide which one to chose. In your particular case, there is only a single function, that one is chosen.

Would you add an additional function `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Derived&)`, that one would be chosen by the compiler, as it is a better match for arguments of type `std::ostream` and `Derived`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 that is wrong. Compiles perfectly fine without the friend if you replace the access to `b.m_str` with a public getter.

Comment: Never mind me, I thought that the function was defined in the class. Sorry!

Comment: OP never asked about inheritance of friendly-ness though. Otherwise this question would be a duplicate.

Comment: You might be right and I might have misunderstood that first sentence of the question.

Comment: Rewrote my answer, as I did get the question wrong when I wrote my first answer.